# Where is the pack-a-punch machine located exactly on Mob of the Dead?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

On the zombie map pack. Mob of the Dead. Where is the pack-a-punch machine located exactly? I've been wondering this for hours. Please, I would really appreciate if anyone could tell me exactly where it is.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to find the five parts to make the plane and head to the Golden Gate Bridge. Well it takes you there anyway. It's the only place that I have seen the Pack-a-Punch machine.

Here's a video showing how to achieve this:

If you're not familiar with the layout of the level you can find more walkthroughs on youtube.